# Generate QR Code in php without Internet

Tags: php, qr-code

I need to Generate QR Code in my Intranet Portal.

I found many Codes in php to Generate QR Code. But all those codes need Internet access to Generate a Complete QR Code.

What i need is to Generate QR Code without accessing Internet.

Because it may slowdown the Network and reduce the performance of Server.

Please help me to Solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "require internet"? There are many solutions in php which are self contained. So you obviously need to contact the server the code is executed on, but that might well be inside your own network. Also these solutions can be used on cli level.

Comment: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ will do the job, you can do it at localhost with xampp/wampp without internet.

Comment: @RC I'm afraid that answer you referred needs Internet connection. I wont run in independent system which doest have internet.

Comment: "Implemented purely in PHP, with no external dependencies (except GD2 if needed)." so I would say no internet required

Comment: @RC its giving error as The Image cannot be displayed because it contains error.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look and found this, looks like what you're looking for: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

> PHP QR Code is open source (LGPL) library for generating QR Code, 2-dimensional barcode. Based on libqrencode C library, provides API for creating QR Code barcode images (PNG, JPEG thanks to GD2). Implemented purely in PHP, with no external dependencies (except GD2 if needed).

**EDIT** I never used it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: its giving error as The Image cannot be displayed because it contains error

Comment: I merely provided you with a url to a script, and like I said, I did not use it before. If you have a question specific to the script, you'll have to start a new question providing details of what you tried, as for this one, my answer addressed your question about what to use...

Comment: you are welcome, and even more if you select my answer as the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've released an open source PHP library to generate QR codes.

https://github.com/edent/QR-Generator-PHP

Can easily be installed on a server (just copy and paste the directory).

You can create a QR by calling

`http://yourserver/qr/php/qr.php?e=M&size=640&d=http://example.com`